# Are functions of bounded variation a.e. differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

In general, it is well known that, on the real line, say on $[0,1]$, if a function $f$ is of (pointwise) bounded variation, meaning that 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})| <+\infty
$$
for every partition ${x_i}_{0}^n$ of $[0,1]$, then $f$ can be written as the difference of two monotone functions, hence it is differentiable a.e. w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.

I am wondering if the same is true for $BV$ functions  in $\mathbb R^d$ for $d \ge 2$.

Of course, the right definition of $BV$ in $d$-dimensional domains passes through the theory of distributions: $f \colon \Omega \subset \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ is in $BV(\Omega)$ if it is an $L^1$ function whose distirbutional gradient $Df$ can be represented by a finite Radon measure (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_several_variables)).

> **Question 1.** Let $f \colon \Omega \subset \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be in  $BV(\Omega)$. Is it true that $f$ is differentiable a.e. with
>   respect to the Lebesgue measure?

What I know is that they are approximately differentiable a.e. (in view of Calderon-Zygmund Theorem) so an approximate differential exists a.e. but I am not aware of any link between the approximate differentiability and the pointwise a.e. one.

---

### Addendum.

In view of Mizar's answer, it seems that the answer to **Q1** is negative, as it has been exhibited a $BV$ function which does not have even a continuous a.e. representative (in $L^1$).

While checking the details of the answer I received, I would like to ask another version of question above (do not know if still meaningful or not).

> **Question 2.** Let $f \colon \Omega \subset \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be in $BV(\Omega)$. Assume further $f \in C^0(\Omega)$ i.e. it is continuous. Is it true that $f$ is differentiable a.e. with
>   respect to the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: How about including the definition of BV for $n$-dimensional domain?  Is it this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#BV_functions_of_several_variables having to do with the distributional derivative being a Radon measure?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Sure, I will edit accordingly. I did not write the definition because I thought it was something definitely well known.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. Take a dense countable set $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and a sequence $(r_i)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\sum_i r_i^{d-1}<\infty$. Then the function
$$f=1_{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_{r_i}(x_i)}$$
is in $BV(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (since $|\bigcup B_{r_i}(x_i)|\le C\sum_i r_i^d$ and $f$ is the limit in $L^1$ of the functions $1_{\bigcup_{i=1}^k B_{r_i}(x_i)}$, whose gradients have total variation bounded by $C\sum_i r_i^{d-1}<\infty$).

Now, for any Lebesgue point $x_0$ of $f$ in the closed set $\{f=0\}$, no representative $g$ is continuous at $x_0$ (*representative* means a function which coincides a.e. with $f$). Indeed, $x_0$ lies in the closure of the open set $\bigcup B_{r_i}(x_i)$, so it belongs to the closure of $\{g=1\}$. On the other hand, since $x_0$ is a Lebesgue point for $f$, it must also belong to the closure of $\{g=0\}$. This shows that $g$ is not even a.e. continuous (since the set $\{f=0\}$ has positive measure).

---

### Addendum.

The answer is still no even assuming $f$ continuous. Below I construct an example where the differentiability of $f$ fails on a Borel set of positive measure.

Choose a countable dense set $\{x_i\}$ in $B_1(0)$ and a sequence $r_i>0$ such that $\sum_i r_i^{d-1}<\infty$ and $\sum_i|B_{r_i}(x_i)|<|B_1(0)|$. In particular, $r_i\to 0$. Using Besicovitch covering theorem, up to a subsequence we can assume that the balls $B_{r_i}(x_i)$ have bounded overlapping (i.e. any point lies in at most $N$ such balls); in doing this, we could lose the density of $\{x_i\}$ but we still have $B_1(0)\subseteq\overline{\cup_i B_{r_i}(x_i)}$.

Let $S:=B_1(0)\setminus\cup_i\overline{B_{r_i}(x_i)}$. We remark that $|S|>0$ and that, for any $N\ge 1$, $S\subseteq\overline{\{x_i\mid i>N\}}$. It follows that we can find a sequence of positive radii $R_i\to 0$ such that
$S\subseteq\cup_{i\ge j}B_{R_i}(x_i)$ for all $j\ge 1$: by compactness, we can find $n_1>0$ such that
$$S\subseteq\overline{\{x_i\mid i>0\}}\subseteq\cup_{i=1}^{n_1}B_1(x_i),$$
then we use the above remark with $N=n_1$ and we find $n_2>n_1$ such that
$$S\subseteq\overline{\{x_i\mid i>n_1\}}\subseteq\cup_{i=n_1+1}^{n_2}B_{1/2}(x_i),$$
and so on.

Now the function $f(x):=\sum_i R_i(1-r_i^{-1}|x-x_i|)^+$ (a superposition of 'traffic cones' with heights $R_i$ placed on our balls $B_{r_i}(x_i)$) is continuous, as it is a uniform limit of continuous functions, thanks to the bounded overlapping. It also lies in $BV(\mathbb{R}^d)$ thanks to the assumption $\sum_i r_i^{d-1}<\infty$.

I claim that $f$ cannot be differentiable at $x$, for any $x\in S$. Indeed, as $x$ is a minimum point for $f$, we would have $\nabla f(x)=0$. But there is a sequence
$i_k\to\infty$ with $x\in B_{R_{i_k}}(x_{i_k})$, so $f(x_{i_k})\ge R_{i_k}\ge|x-x_{i_k}|$, which contradicts $\nabla f(x)=0$ (since $x_{i_k}\to x$).

Comment: What a nice and complete answer! Thanks a lot, I have checked it and it seems correct. +1 ;-)

Comment: Yet one more question: what about $W^{1,1}$ functions? Could your examples be adapted to the $W^{1,1}$ setting or on the contrary is it true that in $W^{1,1}$ differentiabiliy a.e. holds true (I am assuming $d \ge 2$, of course)? Thanks!

Comment: The series defining the function $f$ in the second example converges in $C^0\cap W^{1,1}$, so it is a counterexample for $W^{1,1}$ as well. If you impose that $\sum_i r_i^{(d-p)/p}<\infty$, you also get a counterexample in $C^0\cap W^{1,p}$, for $p<d$. As you probably know, functions in $W^{1,p}$ are continuous and differentiable a.e. if $p>d$. I expect that continuous counterexamples exist in the borderline case $p=d$, but probably it requires more work.