# Convergence of the difference quotient of a BV function

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Consider a BV function $u \in BV(\mathbb{R}^N; \mathbb{R}^N)$. 
What can be said about the difference quotient 
$$
\frac{u(x+\epsilon y)-u(x)}{\epsilon}
$$
regarding its convergence as $\epsilon \to 0$? That is, in what sense does it converge to the derivative $Du = D^{a.c.} u + D^{sing} u$? Under what assumptions does the convergence hold almost everywhere?

Comment: What is the meaning of the quotient if N>1?

Comment: But then converging to anything as ||h|| goes to zero, seems problematic even for N=1 and u(x)=x

Comment: @PietroMajer Actually, I've edited the question now.

Comment: Now the quotient depends on $y$, but the putative limit does not ….

Comment: Maybe you want to consider $\frac{u(x+ty) - u(x)}{t}$ for fixed $y\in \mathbb R^N$ and to study it as a function of $x$ depending on a parameter $t$?

Comment: OK then we have weak* convergence to the derivative in the direction $y$ (if $\|y\|=1$) as $\epsilon \to 0$. Convergence a.e. is not well-defined (what do you mean by convergence of functions pointwise to a measure?) See also a [related post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272282).