# Weak estimate for difference quotient of BV function

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

In an answer to the question [Weak Lebesgue spaces and an estimate for BV functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328467/weak-lebesgue-spaces-and-an-estimate-for-bv-functions) it was remarked that if  $u\in BV(\mathbb R^N)$ then there exists a Lebesgue negligible set $F \subset \mathbb R^N$ such that
$$
|u(x) - u(y)| \le c_N |x-y| (M_R Du(x) + M_R Du(y))
$$
for $x,y\in \mathbb R^N \setminus F$ with $|x-y|\le R$, and 
$$
M_R Du(x) = \sup_{r\in(0,R)} \frac{|Du|(B_r(x))}{|B_r(x)|},
$$
where $|B_r(x)|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of $B_r(x)$.

Also,  $x\mapsto M_R Du(x)$ belongs to the weak $L^1$ space.

> - Is it true that $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exist $F_1, F_2$ such that 
>     $$M_R Du = F_1 + F_2$$
>     and 
>     $$\| F_1 \|_{w-L^1} \le \epsilon \quad \| F_2 \|_{L^1} \le C_\epsilon ,$$
>     where $C_\epsilon$ is some constant that depends on $\epsilon$?
> - If not, under what additional assumptions is it true?

Comment: Where does the question originate from? Why do you want such a decomposition of $M_R Du$?

Comment: @user111164 To understand better the role of $L^1$ vs weak-$L^1$ in this estimate.